# Using django filter() with a querset as args or kwargs

Tags: django, django-models

How to I make the following possible?

models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    #...
    regions = models.ManyToManyField(Region)
```

elsewhere...

```
regions = Region.objects.all()
articles = Article.objects.filter(regions=regions)
```

Currently, the 'articles' retrieved are only from a match with the first region in the queryset, i.e. regions[0].

Of course I would like to get article matches from 1-n regions found.

Kind thanks.

Daryl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe this can help:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#s-in

With that in mind, you could rewrite your code like this:

```
regions = Region.objects.all()
articles = Article.objects.filter(regions_in=regions)
```

And it should work all right.

Comment: Right on!  And I added .distinct() for a little more fidelity.  Thx Fed'